# Setting Directory for Paclet Deploy (Creation)

Tags: packages, paclets, pathfinding

In the sample code below, I am trying to set the location for Paclet creation.  The desired path is:

C:\Users\colin\Desktop\Packages

The "Packages" folder exists as I am able to archive existing packages into the paclet and extract them to a new location (not shown)

The problem is that currently I can only create the paclet to the desktop.  In the example code below, the final Paclet location is:

C:\Users\colin\Desktop\LWAPaclet-05.01.2021.1.paclet

as opposed to:

C:\Users\colin\Desktop\Packages\LWAPaclet-05.01.2021.1.paclet

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
tempDir = "C:/Users/colin/Desktop/Packages";
SetDirectory[tempDir];
VersionString = DateString[{"Day", ".", "Month", ".", "Year", ".1"}];
p = PacletObject[
   <|
    "Name" -> "LWAPaclet",
    "Version" -> VersionString,
    "Creator" -> "Colin Lyle Jordan",
    "Description" -> "Custom Paclets",
    "Extensions" -> {
                    {"Kernel", "Context" -> "LWAPackage`"}
                    }
|>]

Put[p, FileNameJoin[{tempDir, "PacletInfo.wl"}]]
PacDir = CreatePacletArchive[tempDir]
```

Comment: `?CreatePacletArchive` reveals that you can provide `tempDir` as a second argument. Is that the answer?

Comment: thanks @Kuba.  Sorry for late response